# How to escape double quotes in monit config file?

Tags: ubuntu, escaping, monit

I'm using monit on ubuntu to monitor my server and my plan is that monit alerts me via e-mail if special events occur. The problem is that i have to define a password that contains a double quote. Passwords with special characters have to be surrounded by double quotes (not single quotes) that interfere with the one of the password. Is there any way to escape this?

```
set mailserver
 smtp.example.com
 port 465
 username example@provider.com
 password "ex"ample" # password should be ex"ample, this and ex\"ample dont work
 using SSL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode a double quote in `monit` config as its hexadecimal ASCII: `\0x22`